# Python - Pandas - grouped by variable condition (ANS: isin())

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe "data_f" that want to be filtered by a condition X that is defined by the users elsewhere, and then follow by groupby how do I do that?

```
data_f[(data_f['Core'] == X)]
```

where X is a variable,  can be one number 0, 1, 2, 3 or both "0 and 1", "0 and 2" or all "0,1,2,3"...etc
something like

```
data_f[(data_f['Core'] == 0,1,2,3)].groupby(.....)
```

I think this is a more general python question.

somehow .filter function is not working for me so I an trying this way..
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put those numbers in a list *X*, for instance, `X = [0,1,2,3]` and then use `isin()` method for filtering:

```
data_f[data_f['Core'].isin(X)].groupby(...)
```